# Word for a word that was the ancestor for another word?

Tags: terminology

Modern Icelandic *maður* is from Old Icelandic *maðr*.

To relate the latter to the former, I would say "Old Icelandic *maðr* is the ___ of Modern Icelandic *maður*." What linguistic term goes in the blank?

Is there another term for a meaning the other way round, i.e., that fits the blank in this sentence: "Modern Icelandic *maður* is the ___ of *maðr*."

I thought about *ancestor* for the first blank and *descendant* for the second, but I am not sure if this is correct linguistic terminology.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Ancestor" and "descendant" are indeed the correct terms if there is a direct line of descent. Otherwise you would say that they are cognates.

Answer (score 0):

For ancestor, "reflex" is also used, i.e. Icelandic madur is the reflex of Old Norse madr. Also, derivative works: madur derives from madr.

Source or origin and the prefix proto- as in proto-form, proto-sound might work for the madr is the source of madur or the proto-form.

Comment: Reflex = descendant, not ancestor (as your example correctly shows).